# how to modify attribute values from xml tag with python

Tags: python, xml, lxml, graphml

I have many graphml files starting with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/graphml"  
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/graphml">
```

I need to change the xmlns and xsi attributes to reflect proper values for this XML file format specification:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns"  
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns 
 http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd">
```

I tried to change these values with BeautifulSoup like:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(myfile, 'html.parser')
soup.graphml['xmlns'] = 'http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns'
soup.graphml['xsi:schemalocation'] = "http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd"
```

It works fine but it is definitely too slow on some of my larger files, so I am trying to do the same with lxml, but I don't understand how to achieve the same result. I sort of managed to reach the attributes, but don't know how to change them:

```
doc = etree.parse(myfile)
root = doc.getroot()
root.attrib
> {'{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}schemaLocation': 'http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/graphml'}
```

What is the right way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1):

When you say that you have many files "starting with" those 4 lines, if you really mean they're exactly like that, the fastest way is probably to entirely ignore that fact that it's XML, and just replace those lines.

In Python, just read the first four lines, compare them to what you expect (so you can issue a warning if they don't match), then discard them. Write out the new four lines you want, then copy the rest of the file out. Repeat for each file.

On the other hand, if you have namespace attributes anywhere else in the file this method wouldn't catch them, and you should probably do a real XML-based solution. With a regular SAX parser, you get a callback for each element start, element end, text node, etc. as it comes along. So you'd just copy them out until you hit the one(s) you want (in this case, a graphml element), then instead of copying out that start-tag, write out the new one you want. Then back to copying. XSLT is also a fine way to do this, which would let you write a tiny generic copier, plus one rule to handle the graphml element.